# How can I temporarily represent a high res image with a box in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have multiple complicated vector images in a document with multiple artboards. Zooming and moving around can sometimes cause Illustrator to stall for a few seconds. I'd like to temporarily hide the high res images to decrease load on memory and make it easier for Illustrator to do things, but I'd like to have the images replaced by gray boxes or some indicator that an object is still there.

Is this possible? When I use the actual "Hide" function it seems to simply remove the objects visually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply rasterize effect with lower res on object/layer/group/image and lock it. Important are *effect* and *lock* otherwise you get no benefit. Its now an image and you can revert it to a whatever object it was by disabling rasterize in appearances panel. Memory usage itself is unlikely to be the issue.

Or to truly save memory just relinkthe file to a empty box. Dont know why memory would be a issue this day and age but then mac users are known to have bad options regarding stuff like this.

Comment: thanks, that works. I have an old 2015 macbook and have some big stuff running in the background typically so sometimes i have memory issues

Comment: @dylan well, memory is cheap all my computers since 2005 have had more than 32 Gigabytes of memory (yes even laptops). Dont remember running out of memory since 2010 and i do memory intensive stuff all the time.

Comment: I only have 8 Gigabytes. Maybe it's not memory, that was just my guess. Either way your suggestion helped with the latency issue was